# Azure resource manager vm status

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-resource-manager

I used Azure Resource Manager to create a resource group with a couple of VMs and other resources.

How can I read a VM status for a VM that was provisioned, using Azure Resource Manager (ARM), as a resource in a resource group ?

With classic VMs, old scripts use:

```
$vm.InstanceStatus
```

However, when I switch to the Azure Resource Manager mode

```
Switch-AzureMode AzureResourceManager
```

The VM object doesn't recognize the .InstanceStatus as a valid variable.

Answer (score 4):

The PowerShell one-liner that you are looking for might look something like this:

```
Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName "MyRGName" -Name "MyVmName" -Status | `
    select -ExpandProperty Statuses | `
    ?{ $_.Code -match "PowerState" } | `
    select -ExpandProperty DisplayStatus
```

This will show `VM deallocated` if the VM is stopped or `VM running` if it's running.

To get hold of the `Get-AzureRmVm` cmdlet, run the following:

```
Install-Package AzureRM
Install-AzureRM
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Get-AzureVM -ResourceGroupName <RGName> -Name <VMName> -Status
```

In the result, you should see Statuses, and within this you should see one that looks like "PowerState/running", etc.

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: I moved to AzureRM. And initially I wanted a direct way to get hold of the status as a variable, to be used within a script, rather than being able to simply read it in the VM definition. Thanks anyway. I hope your answer will be found helpful to someone else. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have provided a script to be able to do this thanks to the examples above.

https://miteshc.wordpress.com/2016/02/24/automation-runbook-shutdown-azurearmvm-with-tags/

extract

$ResourceGroup = "RG_Name"
$VMs = Find-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupNameContains $ResourceGroup | 
`Where-Object {$_.Tags.Name-eq "Autoshutdown" -and $_.Tags.Value -eq "Yes"}
Foreach ($VM in $VMs)
{
$VMStatus = Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $vm.Name -Status |`
    select -ExpandProperty Statuses | ?{ $_.Code -match "PowerState" } | select -ExpandProperty displaystatus

```
   if($VMStatus -eq "VM Running")
       {
          Write-Output "status of" $vm.Name "is" """$VMStatus"""
          Stop-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $ResourceGroup -Name $vm.Name -Force
       }
       else
       {
          Write-Output "status of" $vm.Name "is" """$VMStatus"""
       }
```

}

Thanks !
Mitesh

Answer (score -1):

You can read the provisioning status of a Azure VM provisioned under ARM using the PowerShell code below:

```
$vm = Get-AzureRmVM -Name <VMName> -ResourceGroupName <ResourceGroupName>
$vm.ProvisioningState
```

This is tested with the latest Azure PowerShell revision (1.0.1) which is released on November 2015.

Comment: The provisioning state of a VM only tells you what the status of provisioning a VM is, not whether it is running, stopped, etc.